# Understanding how haskell applicative functors are applied

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative, option-type

I just have a quick question about applicative functors to help me get a grasp on them. This is just stuff I am applying in ghci.

```
[(+3),((-) 3),(*3)] <*> [4]
[7,-1,12]
```

This makes sense to me. Basic application. But when trying:

```
[(Just (+3)),(Just ((-) 3)),(Just (*3))] <*> [Just 4]
```

I am given a large amount of errors. I have somewhat of an understanding why; there are two data constructors (`[]` and `Maybe`) and the `<*>` function only "peels back" one of them. What I'd like to assist my understanding is what exactly haskell is trying to do step by step until it fails, and how you could get around it and have this successfully compute to:

```
[(Just 7),(Just -1),(Just 12)]
```

Comment: Please include the errors you got in the above.

Comment: The issue is that, although `Maybe` and `[]` are both instances of Applicative, and so therefore is their composition (which is what you're using here), that instance isn't contained in the prelude. After googling, I see that this is defined in [Data.Functor.Compose](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html#t:Compose) - if you import this module and the `Compose` type then you should be able to get this to work using `Compose [] Maybe`. (But I haven't tried, and aren't in a position to at the moment.)

Comment: I think you mean `[(+ 3), ((-) 3), (* 3)]` for your list of functions.

Answer (score 8):

You have two different `Applicative` instances. It is true that

```
Just (* 3) <*> Just 4 == Just 12
```

but the `[]` instance just tries to *apply* each "function" in the first list to each value in the second, so you end up trying to apply

```
(Just (* 3)) (Just 4)
```

which is an error.

(More precisely, your list of `Just` values just has the wrong type to act as the first argument for `<*>`.)

Instead, you need to need to map `<*>` over the first list.

```
> (<*>) <$> [(Just (+3)),(Just ((-) 3)),(Just (*3))] <*> [Just 4]
[Just 7,Just (-1),Just 12]
```

(Mapping a higher-order function over a list is how you usually get a list of wrapped functions in the first place. For example,

```
> :t [(+3), ((-) 3), (* 3)]
[(+3), ((-) 3), (* 3)] :: Num a => [a -> a]
> :t Just <$> [(+3), ((-) 3), (* 3)]
Just <$> [(+3), ((-) 3), (* 3)] :: Num a => [Maybe (a -> a)]
```

)

---

`Data.Functor.Compose` mentioned in the comments is another option.

```
> import Data.Functor.Compose
> :t Compose [(Just (+3)),(Just ((-) 3)),(Just (*3))]
Compose [(Just (+3)),(Just ((-) 3)),(Just (*3))]
  :: Num a => Compose [] Maybe (a -> a)
> Compose [(Just (+3)),(Just ((-) 3)),(Just (*3))] <*> Compose [Just 4]
Compose [Just 12,Just (-1),Just 12]
> getCompose <$> Compose [(Just (+3)),(Just ((-) 3)),(Just (*3))] <*> Compose [Just 4]
[Just 12,Just (-1),Just 12]
```

The definition of `Compose` is very simple:

```
newtype Compose f g a = Compose { getCompose: f (g a) }
```

The magic is that as long as `f` and `g` are both (applicative) functors, then `Compose f g` is *also* a (applicative) functor.

```
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
    fmap f (Compose x) = Compose (fmap (fmap f) x)

instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (Compose f g) where
    pure x = Compose (pure (pure x))
    Compose f <*> Compose x = Compose ((<*>) <$> f <*> x)
```

In the `Applicative` instance, you can see the same use of `(<*>) <$> ...` that I used above.